# How to pass parameters through Java Validator messages?

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-validator

Currently, I have something like

```
@NotNull(message="{err.required}")
@Size(min=1, message="{err.required}")
private String firstName;
```

In my `messages.properties`, I have

```
err.required={0} is required.
```

It works but it prints out `firstName is required.` which is ugly. It passed the variable name `firstName` as parameter in `{0}`.

How do I pass in something like "**First name**" instead? So it will become `First name is required.`

Comment: Possibly SpEL could be used for that. You might have a look at it (Spring Expression Language).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
@NotNull(message="First name {err.required}")
@Size(min=1, message="First name {err.required}")
private String firstName;

@NotNull(message="Last name {err.required}")
@Size(min=1, message="Last name {err.required}")
private String lastName;
```

and in properties file

```
err.required= is required.
```

or if you want to be more clear, you could add your own annotation and validator:

```
@Target({ METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE, CONSTRUCTOR, PARAMETER })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = { NotEmptyValidator.class })
public @interface NotEmpty {

    String message() default "{customMessage} is required.";

    Class<?>[] groups() default { };

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default { };

    String customMessage() default "";
}

public class NotEmptyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotEmpty, String>
{
    @Override
    public void initialize(NotEmpty notEmpty)
    {        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context)
    {
        return value != null && !value.isEmpty();
    }
}
```

Then your field

```
@NotEmpty(message="{err.required}"
          customMessage="First name")
private String firstName;
```

And in properties (although it's not mandatory since you can default the value to this):

```
err.required={customMessage} is required.
```

Comment: This will add the content of the validated field. The question was about passing a custom string in the message.

Comment: @UweAllner I've modified the answer to cover what you thought the OP meant.

Comment: Uwe is right, I am not looking for the value itself  but I want any String to be provided as parameter. I will try this later once I get home. Thanks!

Comment: @m3th0dman is `{customMessage}` automatically added to `context`?

Comment: @beerbajay Yes; I tested the code and it works. Note that I used HibernateValidator implementation of BeanValidation, not SpringValidator and I do not know if it depends on implementation or is API specific thing.

Comment: Confirmed working! Although a little hassle to setup all validators like this, this is better than manual validation :) Thank you very much!