# How to write a java variable value in message of validator

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

For OTP length I am using 6, which I am taking from a variable

```
static final int OTP_LENGTH = 6;

@Size(min = OTP_LENGTH, max = OTP_LENGTH, message = "OTP Length should be {OTP_LENGTH} !!")
private String otp;
```

For which I am getting error mesage, if size is not of OTP_LENGTH.

```
"fieldErrors": [
    {
      "field": "password",
      "message": "Not a Base64 string !!"
    },
    {
      "field": "otp",
      "message": "OTP Length should be {OTP_LENGTH} !!"
    }
  ]
```

I also tried

```
@Size(min = OTP_LENGTH, max = OTP_LENGTH, message = "OTP Length should be ${OTP_LENGTH} !!")
private String otp;
```

But, OTP_LENGTH 6 is not setting.

Expectation :- "OTP Length should be 6 !!"

And, is there any other validator which takes only 1 length.

@Size, @Length can take max, @Size(max = OTP_LENGTH), but again min will be 0. If I will not override message, it will show length should be between 0 & 6.

Comment: What is the actual message which you do currently see?

Comment: "message": "OTP Length should be {OTP_LENGTH} !!". It's not replacing with 6

Comment: I was following this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020035/how-to-pass-parameters-through-java-validator-messages

Comment: what about: `OTP Length should be '${OTP_LENGTH}' `?

Comment: tried. No luck.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use `min` and `max` fields from @Size annotation, e.g.:

```
@Size(min = OTP_LENGTH, max = OTP_LENGTH, message = "OTP Length must be between {min} and {max}")
private String otp;
```

For value, you can `validatedValue` property.

Comment: can't we use OTP_LENGTH? And is there any alterative to take only one length. Size, Length takes min, max

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020035/how-to-pass-parameters-through-java-validator-messages, it's working for them